# Is it possible to have 2 buttons within the same layout that have the same functionality?

Tags: android

I have a long list with search options. I want a button at the top and bottom of the list to 'search'. Both buttons would have the same functionality. I thought it would be possible to just copy and past the first button in the xml layout at the end, but the button at the end has no functionality. How do I get this to work without adding a bunch of extra code in my Activity?

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/save_search_options"
    android:text="Search" android:textSize="25dip"></Button>

<!--search options in between-->


<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/save_search_options"
    android:text="Search" android:textSize="25dip"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add

```
Button
 ...
 android:onClick="functionName"
```

to both buttons then create a function in your `Activity` like

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
     //some logic
}
```

then it will know which you pressed. However, it may be more efficient to just keep the one `Button` on top of the `List`

Answer (score 1):

If you attach the same `onClickListener` to each, then they will have the same functionality. You can do this in XML to avoid code by using the `android:onClick` XML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have two buttons with identical id. Rename one of them and assign the listener to both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Set different id for the 2 button so the code will be like this

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/top_save_search_options"
    android:text="Search" android:textSize="25dip"></Button>

<!--search options in between-->


<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bottom_save_search_options"
    android:text="Search" android:textSize="25dip"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and declare the button in your activity with different id you've set and you can set same listener to the both button